# Как определить было ли прикасание к треугольнику?

Tags: android, java, opengl

С помощью OpenGL ES 1.0 отрисовываю треугольники.

Как определить было ли прикасание к треугольнику, если у нас есть координаты прикасания пальца на экране?

Comment: А координаты вершин треугольников есть?

Comment: Да, есть координаты исходных треугольников, матрицы преобразований, viewport, т.е. наверное, все данные. Основные проблемы в работе c OpenGL. Если получить координаты преобразованных точек треугольника и преобразовать координаты точки экрана к координатам OpenGL, то я могу решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте получить координаты каждой вершины в screen-space. Мне на ум приходит только метод перемножения V=ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * Vertex[i]. В этом случае вы получите координаты V.x и V.y в пределах от -1 до 1 (на счёт ES-версии не уверен). Получаете таким образом координаты трёх вершин A,B,C. Далее к каждому ребру (AB, BC, CA) строите нормаль. Скажем, пусть нормаль к ребру всегда будет обращена во внутрь треугольника. Далее, если получить скалярное произведение векторов Nab и AD (D - точка касания к экрану, Nab - нормаль к ребру AB), Nbc и BD, Nca и CD, тогда точка будет лежать в треугольнике, если знаки этих произведений буду положительны.

Comment: Имея A, B и C, достаточно выяснить, сонаправлены ли вектора `AB x AD`, `BC x BD`, `CA x CD` или какие-то из них противоположно направлены. Нормали можно не вычислять. (Произведения векторные.)

Comment: Вычислять векторные произведения куда сложнее, чем посчитать скалярные: векторное произведение выполняется для трехмерных векторов (т.е. нужно перевести 2D вектора в 3D, что критично, если обсчитывать каждый треугольник на ЦП), а скалярное можно выполнить и для двухмерных. Нормаль вычислить не проблема: исходный вектор имеет координаты (x,y), тогда нормаль к нему равна (-y,x). Так проще. Можно даже дополнительную память не выделять, а просто поменять местами координаты в том же векторе.

Comment: Хотя... Если подумать, то можно вычислять только координату Z для результирующего вектора в векторном произведении (Zc = Ya*Xb - Xa*Yb) (X и Y всё равно будут по нулям). И просто можно сравнить знаки. Вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

либо мойно пойти обратным путем и использовать функцию unproject, которая из экранных координат получает координаты в пространстве модели (при передаче матрицы трансформации модель-камера-проекция именно данной модели), в качестве экранного z - можно взять значение из буффера глубины

затем, можно попробовать алгоритм из предыдущего ответа для определения треугольника